# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) on line 10

Tags: php, if-statement

Can someone please give me some guidance on how to deal with this error? I'm not a programmer and so have little to no skills / knowledge about this kind of thing. But, I'm keen to learn, and would be really greatful if someone could give me some guidance.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) on line 10
```

The code this relates to is below:

```
<?php 


include 'desciptions.php';
include 'title.php';
$rand=rand(0,67);


else if($rand=='1')
    $desciptions=$d1;
    $title=$m1;

else if($rand=='2')
    $desciptions=$d2;
    $title=$m2;

else if($rand=='0')
    $desciptions=$d0;
        $title=$m0;
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$title' (T_VARIABLE) in /index.php on line 11

Comment: you should start from tutorial its basic syntax error

Comment: Looking at your logic, this can be done in one line. Also please get a tutorial in PHP basics. The right foundation is mandatory

Comment: You should start by checking the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `else`, add `{` and `}` and remove the ticks:

```
<?php 

include 'desciptions.php';
include 'title.php';
$rand=rand(0,67);

if($rand == 1) {
    $desciptions = $d1;
    $title = $m1;
} else if($rand == 2) {
    $desciptions = $d2;
    $title = $m2;
} else if($rand == 0) {
    $desciptions = $d0;
    $title = $m0;
}
?>
```

Also maybe fix `desciptions` to `descriptions`.

Comment: thanks you bro is working

Comment: Glad it works. Some further reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<?php

include 'desciptions.php';
include 'title.php';
$rand = rand(0, 67);


if ($rand == '1') {
    $desciptions = $d1;
    $title = $m1;
} elseif ($rand == '2') {
    $desciptions = $d2;
    $title = $m2;
} elseif ($rand == '0') {
    $desciptions = $d0;
    $title = $m0;
}
?>
```